# Can Pre-Build Events Raise Warnings?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, build-process

I have a custom tool which is set up as a pre-build event, it does some multi-language processing on the source code before it builds.

I was wondering if it was possible for that tool to generate warnings which can be seen in visual studio's list of build warnings, either by outputting a specific string to the console (or by some other method).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look at [MSBuild / Visual Studio aware error messages and message formats](http://blogs.msdn.com/msbuild/archive/2006/11/03/msbuild-visual-studio-aware-error-messages-and-message-formats.aspx).